# Rails 5: FriendlyId TypeError (wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module:))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I am trying to add friendlyid to my application, after I've setup everything I get the following error:

TypeError wrong argument type Symbol expected Module

I inserted `extend :FriendlyId` and `friendly_id :wine_name, use: :slugged` into my model. I also tried to use slug instead of slugged but this didn't work.

I tried different paths but it doesn't seem to work

This is my wines_controller

```
class WinesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_wine, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:details, :pricing, :description, :photo_upload, :more_details, :sets, :location, :update]

  def index
    @wines = current_user.wines
  end

  def new
    @wine = current_user.wines.build
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def create
    @wine = current_user.wines.build(wine_params)
    if @wine.save
      redirect_to details_wine_path(@wine), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @photos = @wine.photos
    @guest_reviews = @wine.guest_reviews
  end

  def details
  end

  def pricing
  end

  def description
  end

  def photo_upload
    @photos = @wine.photos
  end

  def more_details
  end

  def sets
  end

  def location
  end

  def update

    new_params = wine_params
    new_params = wine_params.merge(active: true) if is_ready_wine

    if @wine.update(wine_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  def preload
    today = Date.today
    # Reservations greater than today (upcoming reservations)
    reservations = @wine.reservations.where("start_date >= ?", today)

    render json: reservations
  end


  private
  def set_wine
    @wine = Wine.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
  # Authorize user (current_user == ID 1)
  def is_authorised
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission" unless current_user.id == @wine.user_id
  end

  def is_ready_wine
    !@wine.active && !@wine.price.blank? && !@wine.base_price.blank? && !@wine.wine_name.blank? && !@wine.summary.blank? && !@wine.photos.blank? && !@wine.alcohol.blank? && !@wine.filling.blank? && !@wine.in_stock.blank? && !@wine.address.blank?
  end

  def wine_params
    params.require(:wine).permit(:wine_type, :wine_color, :wine_art, :alcohol, :wine_name, :summary, :address, :is_1, :is_3, :is_6, :is_12, :filling, :base_price, :price, :in_stock, :year, :active)
  end
end
```

Comment: You're calling `extend` with a Symbol argument (`extend :FriendlyId`) but [`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-extend) should be called with a Module as the error states. Perhaps you mean to say `extend FriendlyId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use FriendlyId in your `Wine` model, the error is in there.

It may look something like

```
class Wine < ApplicationRecord
  extend :FriendlyId
  # ...
end
```

The error says that it was expecting a module but received a symbol, remove the `:` from `FriendlyId`

```
class Wine < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  # ...
end
```